# Query at Spring Boot Project when data base is PostgreSQL

Tags: java, jquery, postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on a beginner level Java Spring Boot project. My java application is connected to my database with hibernate which is PostgreSQL. `"POST"` and `"GET"` methods are working without any problem. Now I have to join some variables from `"a"` class to `"b"` class. Based on my researches, I saw that I have to use a method called inner join. In order to do that I have to write a query. Where should I write the query.

Should I write the query at db query section or inside the controller class of Java Project?

I wrote the necessary query for joining the tables but I don't know where to write it on the project.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As you are using Spring Boot and Hibernate already there is no need to implement SQL queries yourself. There is a Spring Boot framework called JPA. It allows to map the database tables to Java objects called entities. This entities can have relationships to each others. Just have a look to any tutorial or blog like Baeldung for details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have an experience with JPA. If not, then please follow below link.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

All you need to do is create a repository which will fetch data from Database. You will require to write query in Repository using @Query annotation. Below link will guide you on using Query with JPA.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query